# How to make divs have 100% body height after adding position: absolute div below the page bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please give me a clue how to achieve that with pure css?
I need to make 2 divs side by side and I have some element that is adding to the one of that divs, but far below it's bottom. The page automatically resizes then, but these 2 divs heights stays unchanged. Is it possible to make them still fit whole page as it is described in the css, or the only solution is to specify their exact heights by script?

Or maybe there's another way to make such a layout with a div added by script?

Let me show it in the fiddle:

```js
window.onload=run;

function run()
{
  document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click", function()
          {
            var d=document.createElement("div");
            d.id="dd";
            d.style.top="2000px";
            d.style.left="0";
            d.style.width="50px";
            d.style.height="20px";
            d.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Test"));
            document.getElementById("col2").appendChild(d);
          });
}
```

```css
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
}
div#col1
{
  background: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
div#col2
{
  background: #eff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10rem;
  right: 0;
}
div#dd
{
  position: absolute;
  background: #f99;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <title>
            Test
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="col1">
            <input type=button id="b1" value="+">
        </div>
        <div id="col2">
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Thank you!

Short update: I just found, that neither html nor body heights were not updated after adding, but browser lets scroll to the newly added div. It's very strange behavior even for the css/html

Comment: the div's need to be absolute positioned? and what browsers are you targeting, IE8+?

Comment: also, if you're going to define styles for the dd div in the css, why not put all of them there instead of having some set with js?

Comment: @Mohamed-Ted No, they ain't, but I don'd know another way to achieve such a layout.
I expect it to work in the modern browsers, so, ie11, and so on is ok

Comment: @Cruiser It doesnt matter, I just made a quick example to explain what is the problem, I can move all styles to the css if it would help

Comment: I just wonder, why ppl downvoted this? Just because do not know the answer?

Comment: The problem here is that the element you add has `position: fixed` which means it gets out of the flow of your columns. It does not contribute by any measure to his parent. It’s as if you took it, and the rest has to deal without it. So you can scroll it, but `<html>` and `<body>` end in the same place. If the element was part of a column, then I would use `display: table` and `display: table-cell`. But this way? No idea.

Comment: No, it does not. It has "absolute", but ok, I understand all of that, the question is, how to do what I need to ;) what way it could be done?

Comment: Okay, but `fixed` and `absolute` do the same thing to the element: they take it out. But what is your goal? Why do you want to add things, and why with `absolute`?

Comment: This is too philosophical question )) 
In brief - it's a part of the little project. I have such a requirement and try to do that. My goal is to add "absolute" div and to make html/body/all related divs to resize. Senthe gave me an idea to use 2 elements for that - static and absolute, to set required margin for static and to hide it then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're aiming for, but maybe overflow: hidden is what you need? It will make it so the div won't expand to include that addition...

```js
window.onload=run;

function run()
{
  document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click", function()
          {
            var d=document.createElement("div");
            d.id="dd";
            d.style.top="2000px";
            d.style.left="0";
            d.style.width="50px";
            d.style.height="20px";
            d.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Test"));
            document.getElementById("col2").appendChild(d);
          });
}
```

```css
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
}
div#col1
{
  background: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
div#col2
{
  background: #eff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10rem;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div#dd
{
  position: absolute;
  background: #f99;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <title>
            Test
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="col1">
            <input type=button id="b1" value="+">
        </div>
        <div id="col2">
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: i think he wants it to expand, but the blue and gray colored divs to expand with it

Comment: I need this new div to be shown, but, at the same time, these 2 "col" divs should still have 100% height on the resized page.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need scrolling - try position:fixed instead of absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all this CSS, all you need to do is to set their height in CSS explicitely:

- first to `height: 100vh`
- after you add new element, to `height: calc(100vh + X)` where X is distance from initial divs bottom to bottom of the added element.

EDIT: Another solution with removed `position: absolute`:

```js
window.onload=run;

function run()
{
  document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click", function()
          {
            var d=document.createElement("div");
            d.id="dd";
            d.style.width="50px";
            d.style.height="20px";
            d.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Test"));
            document.getElementById("col2").appendChild(d);
          });
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body
{
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 5rem 0 0;
}
div#col1
{
  background: #eee;
  width: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
div#col2
{
  background: #eff;
  width: calc(100vw - 10rem);
}
div#dd
{
  background: #f99;
  border: 2px solid red; 
  margin-top: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <title>
            Test
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="col1">
            <input type=button id="b1" value="+">
        </div>
        <div id="col2">
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: 100vh means 100% of viewport height. My document is larger than viewport, why do you think it's better than just 100%?  

What do you mean by "set explicitly"? I don't really understand. Could you please show the fiddle for that?  

The problem is, that I do not know the real distance as it may vary. Of course I did it using js calculations, changing both divs heights in pixels, but, I suppose, there shall be a simpler solution.

Comment: Since you position that additional element absolutely, your html and body elements will never resize accordingly on their own. You need to change some positioning here to make it work. Or calculate all needed heights with js.

Comment: Well, but why? As I see, browser has made this element accessible - I can scroll to it although html and body sizes aint changed. It's strange.   
Of course, it is obvious that it can be done via js resizing.
And it does not work even if I resize html and body - divs remains short. Only divs resizing works.  
Ok, is it possible to do that changing some positioning?

Comment: Thank you, it's a good idea to set position using margins, but it is not exactly what I need because I cannot do that - the "absolute" for that element is actually generated by the lib and cannot be changed because library will replace it back. The goal is, to have arbitrary positioned element, that's why it has "absolute"

Comment: I really like the idea to use margin, this is what margins are intended to. I suppose, these could be combined. I mean, it is possible to add both a static and an absolute elements but to set static opacity to 0, z-index to -100 and size to 1x1. And it should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, it is really a good idea!  
Could you please edit your answer and add such a code, so I could accept it?  
`var d2=document.createElement("div");  
            d2.id="dd2";  
            d2.style.marginTop="2000px";  
            d2.style.width="1px";  
            d2.style.height="1px";  
            d2.style.opacity=0;  
            document.getElementById("col2").appendChild(d2);`